# Deferring blocking Rails requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, long-polling

I found [a question that explains how Play Framework's await() mechanism works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920998/how-does-await-work-in-play) in 1.2.  Essentially if you need to do something that will block for a measurable amount of time (e.g. make a slow external http request), you can suspend your request and free up that worker to work on a different request while it blocks.  I am guessing once your blocking operation is finished, your request gets rescheduled for continued processing.  This is different than scheduling the work on a background processor and then having the browser poll for completion, I want to block the browser but not the worker process.

Regardless of whether or not my assumptions about Play are true to the letter, is there a technique for doing this in a Rails application?  I guess one could consider this a form of long polling, but I didn't find much advice on that subject other than "use node".

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar question about long requests that blocks workers to take other requests. It's a problem with all the web applications. Even Node.js may not be able to solve the problem of consuming too much time on a worker, or could simply run out of memory.

A web application I worked on has a web interface that sends request to Rails REST API, then the Rails controller has to request a Node REST API that runs heavy time consuming task to get some data back. A request from Rails to Node.js could take 2-3 minutes.

We are still trying to find different approaches, but maybe the following could work for you or you can adapt some of the ideas, I would love to get some feedbacks too:

1. Frontend make a request to Rails API with a generated identifier [A] within the same session. (this identifier helps to identify previous request from the same user session).
2. Rails API proxies the frontend request and the identifier [A] to the Node.js service
3. Node.js service add this job to a queue system(e.g. RabbitMQ, or Redis), the message contains the identifier [A]. (Here you should think about based on your own scenario, also assuming a system will consume the queue job and save the results)
4. If the same request send again, depending on the requirement, you can either kill the current job with the same identifier[A] and schedule/queue the lastest request, or ignore the latest request waiting for the first one to complete, or other decision fits your business requirement.
5. The Front-end can send interval REST request to check if the data processing with identifier [A] has completed or not, then these requests are lightweight and fast.
6. Once Node.js completes the job, you can either use the message subscription system or waiting for the next coming check status Request and return the result to the frontend.

You can also use a load balancer, e.g. Amazon load balancer, [Haproxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/). 37signals has a [blog post and video](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/1073-nuts-bolts-haproxy/) about using Haproxy to off loading some long running requests that does not block shorter ones.

Github uses similar strategy to handle long requests for generating commits/contribution visualisation. They also set a limit of pulling time. If the time is too long, Github display a message saying it's too long and it has been cancelled.

YouTube has a nice message for longer queued tasks: "This is taking longer than expected. Your video has been queued and will be processed as soon as possible."

I think this is just one solution.  You can also take a look [EventMachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine) gem, that helps to improve the performance, handler parallel or async request.

Since this kind of problem may involve one or more services. Think about possibility of improving performance between those services(e.g. database, network, message protocol etc..), if caching may help, try out caching frequent requests, or pre-calculate results.